# Parsing JSON response gives null value

Tags: java, json, jackson

My code which parse `JSON`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);        
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(response.toString());
JsonNode entriesNode = rootNode.path("messages");
StoreMessageList objects = mapper.readValue(rootNode.toString(), new TypeReference<StoreMessageLis(){});    
Log.d("JacksonParser", objects.toString());
```

Below is my `POJO` class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class StoreMessageList {

    private String location;

    @JsonProperty("messages")
    List<MessageList> messages;

    public StoreMessageList() {
    }

    public StoreMessageList(String location, List<MessageList> messages) {

        this.location = location;
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public List<MessageList> getMessages() {
        return this.messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(List<MessageList> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StoreMessageList:{location: " + location + ", messages: " + messages + "}";
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class MessageList implements Serializable{

        @JsonProperty("Text")
        private String Text;

        @JsonProperty("DetailPicture")
        private String DetailPicture;

        @JsonProperty("Title")
        private String Title;

        @JsonProperty("ListPicture")
        private String ListPicture;

        public MessageList() {
        }

        public MessageList(String Text, String DetailPicture, String Title, String ListPicture) {
            this.Text = Text;
            this.DetailPicture = DetailPicture;
            this.Title = Title;
            this.ListPicture = ListPicture;

        }

        public String getText() {     
            return this.Text;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.Text = text;
        }

        public String getDetailPicture() {
            return this.DetailPicture;
        }

        public void setDetailPicture(String detailPicture) {
            this.DetailPicture = detailPicture;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return this.Title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.Title = title;
        }

        public String getListPicture() {
            return this.ListPicture;
        }

        public void setListPicture(String listPicture) {
            this.ListPicture = listPicture;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Messages:{Text: " + Text + ", DetailPicture: " + DetailPicture + ", ListPicture: " + ListPicture +
                        ", Title: " + Title + "}";
        }

    }
}
```

Please, help me to get the values instead of null value.
JSON Response:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://10.1.1.228:8880/messages/1"
        }
    },
    "location": "ABC Store",
    "messages": [
        {
            "DetailPicture": "/images/2_detailpic.png",
            "Text": "This is a dummy text. This is a dummy text. This is a dummy text. This is a dummy text. This is a dummy text. This is a dummy text. This is a dummy text. This is a dummy text. This is a dummy text. ",
            "ListPicture": "/images/2_listpic.png",
            "Title": "Test Title"
        },
        {
            "Text": "dummy dummy dummy",
            "ListPicture": "/images/3_listpic.png",
            "Title": "Test News"
        },
        {
            "Text": "dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text du",
            "ListPicture": "/images/4_listpic.png",
            "Title": "News 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You have root `POJO` class, you do not have to use `JsonNode` at all. Try with this: `StoreMessageList objects = mapper.readValue(response.toString(), StoreMessageList.class);`

Comment: Tried but this gives below Exception:                              09-15 10:18:50.960: W/System.err(930): com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.out.show.data.StoreMessageList$MessageList]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)                                                  09-15 10:18:50.960: W/System.err(930):  at [Source: {"_links":{"self":{"href":"http:\/\/10.1.1.228:8880\/messages\/1"}},"location":"ABC Store","messages":[{"DetailPicture":"\/images\/2_detailpic....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MessageList` class is an inner class. Inner class which is not `static` can not exist without instance of outer class. In my opinion you have to mark this class as `static` and since than below code should work properly:

```
ObjectMapper deserializerMapper = new ObjectMapper();
StoreMessageList root = deserializerMapper.readValue(json, StoreMessageList.class);
System.out.println(root);
```